# After button is clicked , Unable to reset the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I entered some data in textbox and after that I clicked on the Button.
After clicked on the button The data should be reset.

```
class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            title: 'React App',
            keywords: 'Type Above'
        }
    }

    inputData = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value)
        this.setState({ keywords: event.target.value ? event.target.value : 'Type Above' })
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Button Clicked');
        this.setState({ keywords: "" });
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>{this.state.title}</h2>
            <form onSubmit ={this.handleSubmit}> 
              <center>
              <input type="text"
                  placeholder="Search Value..." 
                  onChange ={this.inputData} />
              <h3>{this.state.keywords}</h3>
              </center>
              <button> BUtton  </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Data should get reset after button is clicked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `value` prop to your `input`,

```
<input type="text"
  placeholder="Search Value..." 
  onChange ={this.inputData} 
  value = {this.state.keywords}
/>
```

Lear more about [Controlled Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-o4yiev)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "React App",
      keywords: "Type Above"
    };
  }

  inputData = event => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
      keywords: event.target.value ? event.target.value : "Type Above"
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Button Clicked");
    this.setState({ keywords: "" });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.state.title}</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <center>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search Value..."
              value={this.state.keywords === 'Type Above' ? '' : this.state.keywords}
              onChange={this.inputData}
            />
            <h3>{this.state.keywords}</h3>
          </center>
          <button> BUtton </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you didn't assign the `keywords` value to the input, because the value is correctly deleted after you click the button, you can see it here:

```
class Header extends Component {
  state = {
    title : 'React App',
    keywords : 'Type Above'
  };

  inputData = event => {
   console.log(event.target.value)
   this.setState({ keywords: event.target.value ? event.target.value : 'Type Above' });        
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Button Clicked');
    this.setState({ keywords: "" });
  };

  render() {
    const { keywords, title } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 
          <center>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search Value..." 
              onChange={this.inputData}
              value={keywords}
            />
            <h3>{keywords}</h3>
          </center>
          <button>Button </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope this helps, Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `value` attribute for your `input`. You need to add something like this `value={this.state.keywords}`